# ruby regular expression to parse JSON fragment

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a JSON fragment I need to parse:

```
fragment = "\"product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""
```

I want to get the value out of any key given that key's name.

I have tried:

```
fragment.match/\"product name\"\:\"(.+)\"/
```

but I get unterminated string meets end of file.

Can you help me grab the string `12 oz. Coke` ?

Comment: Couldn't you just surround the fragment with `{` and `}` and use a JSON parser?

Comment: No, because it's not well formed, sorry I should have clarified that.

Comment: OK, if it's not well-formed, then we need to know exactly how it's not well-formed because that will directly affect the construction of the regex (assuming regex is the right way to go, then).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to escape quote-signs in regexp, also, add a ?-mark to make the search lazy. This works for me:

```
fragment = "\"product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""

p fragment[/"more keys":"(.+?)"/, 1] # => "another value"
p fragment[/"product name":"(.+?)"/, 1] # => "12 oz. Coke"
```

Edit:

An alternative would be to put the data into a hash:

```
p Hash[fragment.gsub('"','').split(',').map{|x|x.strip.split(':')}]
# => {"product name"=>"12 oz. Coke", "more keys"=>"another value"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the 'value' part in the 'key-value' pattern:

```
str = %q("product name":"12 oz. Coke", "more keys":"another value")
str.scan /".+?":"(.+?)"/
=> [["12 oz. Coke"], ["another value"]]
```

http://rubular.com/r/Add4Ftf4cJ

Answer (score 1):

### Interpolate String into Valid JSON

You can use [JSON#parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) and a little interpolation to turn your string into a normal Ruby [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) object. A Hash will expose all sorts of useful utility methods to get at your data. For example:

```
# use interpolation to convert to valid JSON, then parse to Hash
fragment = "\"product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""
hash = JSON.parse '{%s}' % fragment
#=> {"product name"=>"12 oz. Coke", "more keys"=>"another value"}

# manipulate your new Hash object
hash['product name']
#=> "12 oz. Coke"
hash.keys
#=> ["product name", "more keys"]
hash.values
#=> ["12 oz. Coke", "another value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about all of the formats of JSON, but one method would be to

```
Match the key name  -- probably best to set case insensitive
Match the separator characters
Match anything that is not a termination character into a capturing group:

/product name[\\": ]+([^\\]+)/i
```

Another way, using your method, would be to make the capturing group lazy.  And also remember that in Ruby, you need to use \\ rather than \.  So:

```
/"\\"product name\\":\\"(.+?)\\/i
```

Depending on your data, you might also need to turn on "dot matches newline"

```
/"\\"product name\\":\\"(.+?)\\/mi
```

Comment: thanks, but the first solution is the only one that matches anything, and captures everything after the beginning hit (it catches the "more keys.." part):  fragment.match(/product name[\\": ]+([^\\]+)/i)[1]
 => "12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""

Comment: Using either one of the variations I supplied, I do not see it capturing anything other than the "12 oz coke" into group 1.  There must be something different between what you have supplied here, and your "real" environment.

Comment: At this Ruby regex online tester: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/ruby/index.html  using the string:  "\"product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""  and the regex:  product name[\\": ]+([^\\]+), the result shows 12 oz coke in capturing group 1

Comment: 1.9.3-p448 :001 > fragment = "\"product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""
 => "\"product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\"" 
1.9.3-p448 :002 > fragment.match(/product name[\\": ]+([^\\]+)/i)[0]
 => "product name\":\"12 oz. Coke\", \"more keys\":\"another value\""

Comment: If the part of your comment prior to "fragment.match" represents what you are trying to parse, the regex I supplied matches both of the 12 oz. Coke entries in the line (in capturing group 1 of each match); both on my tester and at the regexplanet tester I mentioned above.  That tester doesn't seem to understand /i, so I just used the regex without the modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Just to demonstrate how you might do this using the builtin JSON parser (if that were an option):

```ruby
require 'json'
fragment = '"product name":"12 oz. Coke", "more keys":"another value"'
hash = JSON.parse('{' + fragment + '}')
hash['product name'] # => "12 oz. Coke"
```